# Update UI when app is in background. Unregister BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to update the UI of my fragment when I receive an event. For that I am using LocalBroadCastReceiver. When I receive the event from my server, I set the data in cache and call sendBroadcast. In onReceive of my receiver I am getting the data from cache and updating the UI.

All this works fine until I unregister the receiver in onStop(). So When I put the app in the background, receiver gets unregistered and onReceive method does not get called.

I want to know is it ok if I do not unregister the receiver on onStop ? If it is not recommended then what should I use in place of BroadcastReceiver so that I can update the data even when the app is in backgroud.

Comment: There is a good change your view is garbage collected if your app is not in the foreground. It's not very reliable to update the UI if it's not in foreground. Just update it when it comes to foreground. And unregister broadcast receivers. It leaks memory

Comment: What is the benefit of updating the UI when the app is not visible? Instead just display the updated UI when the user opens the app again.. And make sure to unregister broadcast receivers always.. Otherwise there will be a memory leak.

Comment: I think you can use onResume to check whether there are pending event in cache to be updated in UI when app back to foreground. so here you have 2 check/possible UI update. 1. from broadcast receiver 2. when onResume

Comment: UI is very heavy and I am doing some other operations on onResume so keeping performance in mind, I wanted to update the UI when the app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Register Broadcast Listener in Manifest file under Application tag:

```
    <receiver android:name="TestReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="<ACTION_NAME>"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

You will receive onReceive, when the app is in background. Also, you will have to create separate class extending BroadcastReceiver class. And, write the name of your class instead of TestReceiver in manifest file.

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }}
```

Comment: But this will keep the Receiver registered forever. Will it not be a possible memory leak ?